# add javascript into html generated BY javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm writing somewhat of a complex sweetalert popup, using its built in "html" command:

```
swal({   
    title: "Popup",
    html:     
      '<p style="font-family:Capriola, sans-serif;font-size: 19px;">' +                  
      '<b>'+title+'</b><br>' +
      '<b>Update Matching</b>' +
      '<div class="input-group">' +
        '<div class="input-group-btn">' +           
          '<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></button>' +
          '<ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" style="width: 245px;">' +      
            '<li class="dropdown-submenu">' +              
                ''+for(var i=0;i<newList.length;i++){+'<li>'+ newList[i]+'</li>' +}' +                                                                  
            '</li>' +                                                             
          '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +                  
      '</div>' +            
      '' +      
      '' +
      '<input id="uNew" type="text" class="form-control roboto" placeholder="New Owner">' +
      '<input disabled id="uCurrent" type="text" class="form-control roboto" placeholder="Current Owner">' +      
      ' <i id="search" onclick="updatebPMNA()" class="fa fa-check-circle fa-2x fa-green"></i>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<br>' +                        
      '</p>',
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false,
  },
```

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu and have it populate based off the data in the javascript object `newList`, which is echoed from PHP at the start of the function.

I'm running into an issue with this line of code:

```
'<li class="dropdown-submenu">' +              
 ''+for(var i=0;i<newList.length;i++){+'<li>'+ newList[i]+'</li>' +}' +                                                                  
'</li>' +
```

If I take out the `for` loop, I can populate the select with a single `<li>`and the code will run, so I'm sure this is the line that's causing drama.

I know I can insert javascript back into this because this line works:

```
'<b>'+title+'</b><br>' +
```

I'm just not sure I can insert an entire `for` loop...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't have the `for` operation in the middle of a string concatenation. Make them separate statements, then append the result of the `for` to the string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually you could `'he'+function(){var s='';for(var i=0;i<200;i++){s+='l';}return s}()+'o world'`

Comment: That's not a `for` statement though - that's an IIFE containing a `for` statement ;)

Comment: You can also use `newList.map().join()` to process the array and return a string containing the concatenated results.

Comment: @Kaiido - any chance you could expand on this solution in an answer?  I'd like to learn BOTH ways of doing this.

Comment: hum it's late here and I don't really want to. The core issue is handled by the answer you got, and by Rory's first comment. His second comment will let you make some google search about IIFE and Barmar's one will give you an even better way of doing what you want to do, using an IIFE or not.

Comment: all good - I appreciate the direction you've pointed me in already, and I do have a workable solution from Axel below.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

separate those statements:

```
var htmlstr = '...'
...
+ '<li class="dropdown-submenu">';


 for( var i=0; i<newList.length; i++ ){
   htmlstr += '<li>'+ newList[i]+'</li>'; 

 htmlstr += '</li>';
```

and then

```
swal({   
    title: "Popup",
    html: htmlstr,
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this captures the rest of the HTML that I'm generating.  maybe I'm not seeing clearly how you're actually constructing this...

Comment: Oh - this works perfectly.  I'd never seen/used javascript's `+=` command before.  This is great!  Thank you!